# Problem with burger menu start position is dropodown ;/

Tags: html, css, menu

I have a problem with the burger menu, the starting position is dropdown;/ I don't know where the error is. You can see it on this page:
https://www.kancelarialatacz.pl/ (pls use mobile view)

```
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
                
    <a class="logo" href="index.html">
        <img class="logo-dark" src="assets/images/logo/Logo-www.png" alt="appy Logo">
        <img class="logo-light" src="assets/images/logo/Logo-wihte.png" alt="appy Logo">
    </a>
</div>
```

Please help me because I'm going crazy with this

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove class (".in") from {id="navbar-collapse-1"} and then it should be work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks from Hardik Trada!
your code should look like bellow:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse pull-right collapse in" id="navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="true" >
```